# VBA Code 64-bit Systems

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error that my code needs to be updated for Office 64-bit systems. I can't understand what changes need to be made as this works fine on Office 32-bit.

```
Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformationAny Lib "kernel32" Alias _
  "GetTimeZoneInformation" (buffer As Any) As Long
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_Comparing32BitSystemsto64BitSystems) and [JKP](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp)

Comment: ok thanks but I am confused here. Should I use the VBA7 or the Win64 attribute?

Comment: error says: please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the Ptrsafe attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read the guidelines provided. I think declaring PtrSafe like this should do it?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTimeZoneInformationAny Lib "kernel32" Alias _
  "GetTimeZoneInformation" (buffer As Any) As Long
```

Answer (score -1):

Windows API functions in 32-bit system and in 64-bit function are different.

Try following code instead.

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformationAny64 Lib "kernel32" Alias _
      "GetTimeZoneInformation" (buffer As Any) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformationAny Lib "kernel32" Alias _
      "GetTimeZoneInformation" (buffer As Any) As Long
#End If
```

Win64 is decleared if the office system is compiled in 64-bit mode, otherwise it is not decleared.

By using Win64 to determine the system is 64-bit or 32-bit, you can use suitable function for your office system.