# How to make VBA code compatible with 64-bit Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, api, excel-2016

I  have an excel running with VB code and it seems fine with  32 version and now when I tested in  office  2016 it  gives the below error

> The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems

Since I am not good in vb I have issues with updating the code. This is my code below and how to update it for the 64-bit compatibility,

```
Declare Function GetSystemDirectory Lib "kernel64" Alias "GetSystemDirectoryA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
'a  íÌÈ Ãí íßæä åäÇß ÌÏæá Úáì ÞÇÚÏÉ ÇáãÚáæãÇÊ ÈÅÓã
'a QtrDate
Global G_SystemPath As String

Function L_FileExist(L_FName As String) As Boolean
'a chick if the file given is found or not
'a input File Name
'a Output
'a   True : if found
'a   False : if not found
   L_FileExist = Not (Trim(Dir(L_FName)) = "")
End Function
Public Function GetWindowsSysDir() As String
    Dim strBuf As String
    strBuf = Space$(250)
    If GetSystemDirectory(strBuf, 250) Then
        GetWindowsSysDir = StringFromBuffer(strBuf)
        AddDirSep GetWindowsSysDir
    End If
End Function

Public Function StringFromBuffer(Buffer As String) As String
    Dim nPos As Long
    nPos = InStr(Buffer, vbNullChar)
    If nPos > 0 Then
        StringFromBuffer = Left$(Buffer, nPos - 1)
    Else
        StringFromBuffer = Buffer
    End If
End Function

Public Sub AddDirSep(strPathName As String)
    strPathName = RTrim$(strPathName)
    If Right$(strPathName, 1) <> "\" Then
        strPathName = strPathName & "\"

    End If
End Sub


Sub L_Secrit()
G_SystemPath = GetWindowsSysDir
If L_FileExist(G_SystemPath & "MSAYAR.DLL") Then
    Sheet1.Cells(400, 2) = " "
    Sheet1.Cells(401, 2) = " "
    Sheet1.Cells(402, 2) = " "
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Code 64-bit Systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198994/vba-code-64-bit-systems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line should be

```
#if VBA7 then
   Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemDirectory Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetSystemDirectoryA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
#else
   Declare Function GetSystemDirectory Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetSystemDirectoryA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
#end if
```

Here is a [nice resource](http://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt) to find 64bit Win32API calls.

Comment: Changing this line will make the API call compatible at least. I don't know what your code does and what it is used for. Why don't you just try and test it?

Comment: yes.. i tested it and its working fine..  very  helpful indeed.

Comment: The file seems ok in  64 bit  but now 32 bit has issues  . its giving me error

Comment: I updated the question this uses the old declare for old VBA versions